# Using nltk and word net to change words from past tense to future tense

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have some strings in pandas dataframe that look like this

```
'reached out to rme and verified',
'scanner has been replaced',
'...'
```

I am trying to convert the string to this

```
'reach out to rme and verify',
'scanner will be replace'
```

The problem I am having is how to do this for each string.

What I tried is this:

```
def past_tense_to_future_tense(df):
    word_list = []
    for sentence in df['resolution']:
        for word in sentence:
            word = WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v')
        word_list.append(word)
    
    df['resolution'] = word_list
    
    return df
df = past_tense_to_future_tense(df)
```

I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this instead of using two for loops since it is pretty slow.

I tried this and it seems to work faster but for some reason it does not change the sentence at all which is odd:

```
def past_tense_to_future_tense(resolution_string):
    new_sentence = ""
    for word in resolution_string:
        word = WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v')
        new_sentence += word
    return new_sentence

df['resolution_conversion'] = df['resolution'].apply(lambda x: past_tense_to_future_tense(x))
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Note that the future tense of `has been replaced` is `will be replaced`.

Comment: What is `df["resolution"]` a Series with list of strings or a string Series?

Comment: @DaniMesejo correct it is a series with list of strings